# Changing the app pool forces XML rather than JSON from web service

Tags: .net, web-services, iis-7, iis-7.5, integrated-pipeline-mode

I have 2 identical sites.
If I have the app pool as classic, the web service (in the picture) will return JSON.
If I change it to integrated mode, it returns XML.

[image]

code

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public EventList GetAllFeaturedEvents(string AppId, string OrderId)
{ }
```

http://www.simpletix.com/Facebook/App/DisplayWidget.aspx?Domain=http://culinary-festival.thisticket.com

http://www.simpletix.com/facebook/app/displaywidget.aspx?domain=http://dev.simpletix.com

Yes.. both sites have:

```
<add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

in `<system.webServer> <handlers>`

Thanks for any leads!